# install-package from local repository - No match was found for the specified search criteria for

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I want to create a basic local repository for software deployment using nuget packages

Find-package/Install-package fails with the following error "No match was found for the specified search criteria"

It happens When I try to install packages located on an internal network share repository and when packages were added using "nuget add"

I've created a Simple test package using the following sequence of Nuget Commands

```
1.- nuget spec mytest  then I fullfilled the .nuspec file with some basic information.
2.- nuget pack mytest.nuget 
3.- nuget add mytest.1.0.0.nupkg -source \\<myhost>\losnuget
```

Then on the target client

Network share was added as resource in trusted mode, it's accesible and get-packageresource recognizes it correctly

but for example, when I use

```
install-package -name mytest -source mynuget
```

I've get the error about

"install-package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Mytest'. Try Get-PackageSource .... "

My nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
 <metadata>
    <id>mytest</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>TheBest author </authors>
    <owners>TheBest owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Nuget test package</description>
    <releaseNotes>some notes</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>TEST Files install</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: What do you get when you run Find-Package and just supply the repo detail ( -Source) for the command (no package name) - this sohuld list all available packages.

Comment: find-package -source  mynuget -> (shows the list of all available packages without problem)    but If I specify the package name: find-package -name mytest -source mynuget, I've already have the error about 'No match...'  .   But IF I use the push option, nuget push <mytest.xx.x.x.nuspec> then I don't have the problem regarding 'Not Match'

Comment: I don't use nuget, but the PS module/script repo which is similar, but it sounds like a name/syntax mismatch. If you use push do the files get the same names as using add?

Comment: What I've see is that `nuget push` adds the .nupkg in the root of the network share, is the same than copy it manually. `nuget add` Creates a package tree folder structure based on package version and it adds some additional files under it, like .nupkg.metadata or '.sha512'